# Spread rows into one row based on similar author id in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

I have a large data in an Excel sheet like:

```
name    author_id   rating
Name1   Id 1        0.72
Name2   Id 2        0.9
Name3   Id 1        0.74
Name4   Id 1        0.76
Name5   Id 2        0.88
Name1   Id 3        0.8
Name3   Id 2        0.86
Name6   Id 3        0.84
Name3   Id 3        0.84
Name4   Id 4        0.78
Name1   Id 4        0.84
Name6   Id 5        0.84
Etc.    …             …
```

I want to group them based on `author_id` and save the output in a text file in this form:

```
Name1   0.72  Name3  0.74  Name4  0.76
Name2   0.9   Name5  0.88  Name3  0.86
Name1   0.8   Name6  0. 84 Name3  0.84
Name4   0.78  Name1  0. 84    
Name6   0.84
```

I have tried the following code, but it didn’t work.

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)

df = read_excel("/Users/admin/Documents/restaurants.xlsx")

df_grp_author_id = df %>%
  group_by(author_id)  %>%
  summarise(name = paste(name), rating, collapse = ', ', rating = paste(rating))
     
write.table(df_grp_author_id , file = "transactionsBy_author_id.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the sequence of row numbers for each `author_id`, and pivot the data to wide.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(n = row_number(), .by = author_id) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = author_id, names_from = n, names_vary = "slowest",
              values_from = c(name, rating))

# # A tibble: 5 × 7
#   author_id name_1 rating_1 name_2 rating_2 name_3 rating_3
#   <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 Id 1      Name1      0.72 Name3      0.74 Name4      0.76
# 2 Id 2      Name2      0.9  Name5      0.88 Name3      0.86
# 3 Id 3      Name1      0.8  Name6      0.84 Name3      0.84
# 4 Id 4      Name4      0.78 Name1      0.84 NA        NA   
# 5 Id 5      Name6      0.84 NA        NA    NA        NA
```

###### Data

```r
df <- read.table(text =
"name    author_id   rating
Name1   'Id 1'        0.72
Name2   'Id 2'        0.9
Name3   'Id 1'        0.74
Name4   'Id 1'        0.76
Name5   'Id 2'        0.88
Name1   'Id 3'        0.8
Name3   'Id 2'        0.86
Name6   'Id 3'        0.84
Name3   'Id 3'        0.84
Name4   'Id 4'        0.78
Name1   'Id 4'        0.84
Name6   'Id 5'        0.84", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please accept my gratitude. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This approach pivots the data to a wide format. The result has one column for each `name` and one row for each `author_id`.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- structure(list(name = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", 
                              "Name1", "Name3", "Name6", "Name3", "Name4", "Name1", "Name6"
), author_id = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5), rating = c(0.72, 
                                                                 0.9, 0.74, 0.76, 0.88, 0.8, 0.86, 0.84, 0.84, 0.78, 0.84, 0.84
)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = rating)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 7
#>   author_id Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 Name5 Name6
#>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1         1  0.72  NA    0.74  0.76 NA    NA   
#> 2         2 NA      0.9  0.86 NA     0.88 NA   
#> 3         3  0.8   NA    0.84 NA    NA     0.84
#> 4         4  0.84  NA   NA     0.78 NA    NA   
#> 5         5 NA     NA   NA    NA    NA     0.84
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>